# How to move a user into another channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to move a user to another channel with my bot. But I don't find any way to do that. Do I miss something or is it just not possible to accomplish with discord.js/discord api?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`channel` is the voice channel you want to put the member in and `GuildMember` is the member:

```
GuildMember.voice.setChannel(channel)
```

I haven't tested this myself but it should work.